# Overlapping dates logic when your are combining tables with common columns-Lead or lag

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in source which I would want to apply a union and remove duplicate and ensure no date ranges are overlapping.

```
Table 1 : Telst_Customer_current
Table 2 : Telst_Customer_history`enter code here`
Table 3 : Telst_Customer_tt
```

**Table 1 data : Telst_Customer_current**

```
cust_id     Account_no       Row_start_date            Row_end_date
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  123        68567             1/1/2012                  5/5/2013  
  123        68567             5/5/2013                  12/31/9999
```

**Table 2 data : Historydata**

```
cust_id     Account_no       Row_start_date            Row_end_date
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 123        68567             1/1/2009                  1/1/2012
 123        68567             1/1/2012                  5/5/2013  
 123        68567             5/5/2013                  12/31/9999
```

When I combine all three tables like this I should get the below resultant table set such that dates don't overlap

**Expected Result:**

```
cust_id     Account_no       Row_start_date            Row_end_date
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   123        68567             1/1/2009                  1/1/2012
   123        68567             1/1/2012                  5/5/2013
   123        68567             5/5/2013                  12/31/9999
```

Tried with lead on dates but finding it difficult
Also is there a quick simple query check to find if the lead logic is working right on overlap failure detection. Appreciate help on this.

Comment: Could you share your query you have tried so far ? Where is the table 3 data ?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing an union ?

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from Table1
Union
Select col4, col5, col6 from Table2
Union 
Select col7, col8, col9 from Table2
```

Comment: No.After doing a union how will i make sure date ranges do not overlap(say when i union current transaction and history transaction

Comment: So, in your example the date ranges that you have provided are exact matches. If that's the case union would solve for it as it would delete the duplicates. However, in your case if it so happens that a date range overlap i,e, in one table the date range is 01-jan - 10-Jan and other one is 8-Jan - 16 Jan your scenarios doesn't cover what happens then. Do you want to make it a one big concatenated span or you chose one over the other and if so which one and why.